# Duda acerca de las colecciones Treeset y el metodo compareTo()

Tags: java, colecciones

Como esta expuesto en el titulo, querria, si es posible, que me aportaran ustedes algo de luz sobre el asunto. Mas concretamente en que es lo que hace,que devuelve, por que es invocado sin llamarlo, por que los elementos de la coleccion se ordenan de esa manera...el metodo compareTo() de la interfaz Comparable. Aqui va el codigo.

```
    import java.util.TreeSet;

public class PruebaTreeSet_186 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Articulo primero=new Articulo(1,"Primer articulo");
        Articulo segundo=new Articulo(2,"Segundo articulo");
        Articulo tercer=new Articulo(3,"Tercer articulo");
        
        TreeSet<Articulo> ordenaArticulos=new TreeSet<Articulo>(); 
        
        ordenaArticulos.add(tercer);
        ordenaArticulos.add(primero);
        ordenaArticulos.add(segundo);
        for(Articulo art:ordenaArticulos) {
            System.out.println(art.getDescripcion());
        }
        
        
    }

}

class Articulo implements Comparable<Articulo>{
    private int numero_articulo;
    private String descripcion;
    
    public Articulo(int num,String desc) {
        numero_articulo=num;
        descripcion=desc;
    }
    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Articulo o) { 
        return numero_articulo-o.numero_articulo;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Un `TreeSet` es en el fondo un *árbol*, no solo un `Set`. Los árboles son en esencia conjuntos ordenados, un ejemplo sencillo con números, si el primer nodo es un 1, los siguientes nunca van a ser menores que 1, los hijos de los siguientes nunca serán menores que sus padres.... etc, Por ejemplo 1 puede tener como hijos 3 y 4, 3 puede tener como hijos 5 y 6, pero no 2 porque sería menor. Eso hará que el *árbol* se reordene metiendo a 2 como hijo de 1... Vamos, que basicamente mantiene el set ordenado, y por eso llama constantemente a compareTo, para saber exactamente dónde meterlo

Comment: @Benito-B Muy buena aportacion, no sabia que se llamaban automaticamente/constantemente , te agradezco mucho la aclaracion.